# Взаимодействие с календарем Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf

Когда щелкаешь на часы в Windows 10, открывается панелька часов, календарь и события.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно добавить событие туда? Наверное надо как-то взаимодействовать с приложением КАЛЕНДАРЬ или пойти с аккаунтом к которому он привязан? Есть  ли информация по этой сфере?

Comment: Нашли что-нибудь?